# Adobe AIR Fullscreen (OS X Mavericks) Menu Bar

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, osx-mavericks

I've been searching for a solution for weeks and have yet to find something solid. Not even those "ugly Mac hacks" have worked, so I look to you guys.

Here's the issue: I'm creating a presentation application in Adobe AIR for Desktop in AS3. One window (not fullscreen) controls the presentation, while the other displays it. Each window would be on a separate monitor. I want to be able to make the second NativeWindow fullscreen, but the OS X menu bar remains visible.

Does anyone know how to get around this, without having users disable "Displays have separate spaces" in System Preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround:

I decided that, upon first run, I would make a call to an AppleScript script that enables *com.apple.spaces spans-displays*. Here's that script:

```
set target to "com.apple.spaces spans-displays"
if ((do shell script "defaults read " & target) is equal to "0") then
    set new_value to "TRUE"
    do shell script "defaults write " & target & " -bool " & new_value
end if
do shell script "killall -KILL loginwindow &" with administrator privileges
```

I use a NativeProcess to run /usr/bin/osascript. The parameter should be the *native path* to your .scpt file.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not use a lot of Adobe AIR functionality you might try to package with [MDM's Zinc](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/). Zinc allows you to create "native" self-contained program executables, which are not dependent on AIR or any other framework being installed.

Comment: No luck -- menu bar remains. I'm not trying to hide the title bar of the window, I'm trying to hide the native OS X menu bar (or at least place the window over it.) I will check out Zinc though. It'd be nice to ditch the Adobe AIR runtime.

Comment: if you don't need the runtime zinc will do that. i have built some fullscreens apps with it as well. the zinc packager app is quite crappy, but the resulting binaries are fine and work well.